# Zip specific files in directory

Tags: linux, command-line, zip

Is there a way I a can zip specific files in a folder.

For example /tmp/data/test/
In the test directory it list

```
images(in this folder are .tiff images)
test.csv
test.pdf
```

I want to zip up just images folder and the test.csv file without the test.pdf and /tmp/data/test being included. The zip file will only have /images and test.csv

```
zip -j test.zip /tmp/data/test/images /tmp/data/test/test.csv
```

(but this only gives me the csv)

```
zip -r test.zip /tmp/data/test/images /tmp/data/test/test.csv
```

(This gives me everything when I only need just images folder the test.csv)

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why the second one would give you anything other than the `images` folder and `test.csv`.

Comment: It's giving me the image folder and test.csv along with subdirectories /tmp/data/test instead of test.zip -> images test.csv

Comment: I can't see anything that would do that. It only zips the files and directories you tell it to.